# how to recuperate seller text and price

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hello im trying recuperate seller text and price.

this is the code

```
<div class="cd">
  <span class="seller"> Vendido por </span>
  <span class="seller_name">
          Cdiscount
        </span>
  <div class="offer_price_section">
    <div>
      <span class="price_offer">
              88,99 €
            </span>
    </div><!---->
  </div>
</div>
```

and my python code, im taking the url from database and need insert in each url the seller and the price so, im doing this:

```
if database.is_connected():
        cursor = database.cursor()
        cursor.execute("sql")
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in records:
            url = urlopen('row[0].encode('utf-8')).read()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
            find = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'cd'}, limit=None)
            for offer in find:
                vendor = offer.span({'class' : 'seller_name'})
                print vendor
```

but when print vendor only get []

and how can do only save info if the seller is Cdiscount?

can help me?

thanks very much

Comment: first check if page use JavaScript to add items to HTML - turn off JavaScript in web browser and load page again. `BS` can't run JavaScript and you may need `Selenium` to control real webbrowser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: not use javascript

Comment: maybe use `offer.find('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})`. `offer.span` may gives you first `span` - `<span class="seller"> Vendido por </span>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find()` or `find_all()`

```
vendor = offer.find('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})
```

**EDIT:** After testing I found it has to be

```
vendor = offer('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})
```

Using `offer.span` you get only first `<span>` in `<div>`.

Using `offer.span(...)` it doesn't search `<span>` inside `<div>` but elements inside `<span>` - it works like `offer.span.find_all(...)`.

Doc: [Calling a tag is like calling find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all)

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = '''<div class="cd">
  <span class="seller"> Vendido por </span>
  <span class="seller_name">
          Cdiscount
        </span>
  <div class="offer_price_section">
    <div>
      <span class="price_offer">
              88,99 €
            </span>
    </div><!---->
  </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, "lxml")
find = soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'cd'})
for offer in find:
    vendor = offer.find('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})
    print(vendor.text.strip())

    vendor = offer.find_all('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})
    print(vendor)

    vendor = offer('span', {'class' : 'seller_name'})
    print(vendor)
```

Result

```
Cdiscount

[<span class="seller_name">
          Cdiscount
        </span>]

[<span class="seller_name">
          Cdiscount
        </span>]
```